# set python.path for jython in java class that running on windows

Tags: java, python, windows, jython

I am newbie for jython, I am able to run native python codes using python interpreter in java. But I need import python modules for extending capabilities.

I have a class like that

```
import org.python.util.PythonInterpreter;

import org.python.core.*;

public class Master {

    public static void main(String a[]) {

        PySystemState sys = Py.getSystemState();
        sys.path.append(new PyString("C:/Program Files/Python/Python36/Lib/site-packages"));
        sys.path.append(new PyString("C:/Program Files/Python/Python36"));

        PythonInterpreter.initialize(System.getProperties(), System.getProperties(), null);
        PythonInterpreter python = new PythonInterpreter();
        python = new PythonInterpreter(null, sys);

        python.exec("import cx_Oracle");

    }

}
```

my jython register in pom.xml

```
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.python</groupId>
        <artifactId>jython</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.4-rc1</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

For IDE I am using Eclipse Neon.3 Release (4.6.3)

and my python modules are in

[image: Python modules]

Everthing seems ok but I am getting the error below

> ImportError: No module named cx_Oracle

I've tried another modules that in the path which mentioned with picture above. What is thing that I am missing?

Comment: Looks like you are trying to import Python3 modules into Jython, which is still at Python2.  I don't think that is going to work.

Comment: my jython version 2.5.4, not python version. Are they releated? I mean, is it necessary to use python 2.x.x with jython 2.x.x? I didn't find releated document about that topic? @DavidCharles

Comment: Python3 introduced breaking changes into the language.  I wouldn't expect Jython2.3 to be able to use Python3 libraries.